# How to avoid DB deadlocks when multiple Kafka messages produced for same item?

Tags: asp.net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, database-deadlocks, confluent-platform

We have 2 difference web applications. lets named them A and B.
When user change analyse of item in A app, A app do stuff things and produce a kafka mesage.

A rest API in B app consume the message via Confluent http sink connector.
The rest API in B app call  SQL Stored Procedure that update records with transaction.

When (happens a lot) the user changing analyze of the same item in A app constantly- a deadlock caused in the DB. because the SP still works on records when another call for same item reach.

what is the best practice to  handle this issue?
manage some global list with current items(IDs) enter to SP and remove them when SP finish? handle it on DB? other suggestion?

some relevant info:
the apps are ASP .Net Core.
stored in load balancing envoirment(AWS).

Any relevant answer is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the same item is always published with the same key (eg use the hashcode of the item). This ensures that all requests from app A will go on the same topic partition.

In app B make sure the procedure call is done in the consumer polling thread (don't spawn a new thread) so that all procedure calls for the same item will be guaranteed to execute sequentially.

This will resolve deadlocks at the cost of performance. For multiple items you can scale horizontally with multiple consumers (as long as you have plenty of partitions). If performance on repeated requests for the same item is too slow then you have a more complex design issue to address.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your answer, the first point -yes, it is always published with the same key.
the second, the procedure execute sequentially, but this API is async so when the procedure is still running reached another API call (by new kafka msg with same key) and execute the procedure for the newer msg- the deadlock caused.
maybe it is a more complex design issue as you mentioned?

Comment: okay - It's the consumption of the message by application B that allows sequential  execution. If all instances of B are in the same consumer group then only one instance will consume records from a given partition, sequentially. When you say a rest API in B consumes the record what does that mean? Why is there a rest API, wouldn't it be easier to just have Kafka consumers listening to messages published by A?

Comment: Okay, I see how http sink connector works, but the questions still remains, do you need an API in the mix, if you just need to react to an event at app A by invoking a procedure then invoking from a Kafka consumer directly in the polling thread is simple. Additional API call breaks that simplicity

Comment: The other point to consider is why there is deadlock - one invocation of the stored proc sounds like it locks the row relating to the item, so another invocation should just wait until the lock is released. Deadlock suggests that the second invocation takes a lock on another row that the first invocation needs and the second invocation needs the row locked by the first. So sounds like the item relates to a bunch of rows across tables. Is that the case?

Comment: there are some locig/manipulation on B app before strore proc call. why does A app not call directly to SP? because the SP not related A app and dont intresting in logic of B app.

Comment: I think you described the case. and that is from my original question: "what is the best practice to handle this issue? manage some global list with current items(IDs) enter to SP and remove them when SP finish?"  
In yours words: "so another invocation should just wait until the lock is released", can you please suggest how?

Comment: I'd still say the best approach is to put Bs logic into the Kafka consumer and avoid B API. When I say 'should' I mean that from what you have described that should happen without you doing anything special. However deadlock suggests multiple tables updated in the stored proc, so more complex so avoid API if you can to keep proc invocation serial.